# CI Build fails for ASP.NET Core application: missing assemblies and code analysers not found

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio Online site with a project configured to use Git as source control. I created an ASP.NET Core for .NET Framework project, and the wizard created the standard components for me. I commited the solution and created a new build in VSO with the ASP.NET Core template. I queued a build using VS2017 Host and the build was a success.

Then I started to work on my project: added several class libraries, a Microsoft.Graph nuget package, etc. The layout of my solution is as this:

- MyProject (ASP.NET core app)
- MyProject.Application (class library)
- MyProject.Application.LicenseGenerator (console application)
- MyProject.Domain.Commands (class library)
- MyProject.Domain.Models (class library)
- MyProject.Domain.Queries (class library)
- MyProject.Infrastructure.Activation (class library)
- MyProject.Infrastructure.Persistance (class library with EF Core)
- MyProject.Infrastructure.Persistance.Office 365 (class library with Microsoft.Graph)

I tested the code, it compiled and worked as expected, so I commited it, created a new pull request and then queued a new build; but alas, this time my build failed during the Build step.

When I analyse the traces, I get a lot of warnings like this one:¨

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.2\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): 
warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not 
locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, 
Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, 
processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. 
If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. 
[C:\a\1\s\MyProject.Infrastructure.Persistance.Office365 
\MyProject.Infrastructure.Persistance.Office365.csproj]
```

The thing is, these warnings are all over the place, and mention several assemblies such as System.Console, System.IO, System.Reflection and many more. Then, finally, I get compilation errors like this one:

```
AccountRepository.cs(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Graph' 
does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly 
reference?)
```

This seems a silly error, because the code is referencing a Microsof.Graph assembly and of course it exists (my code compiles in my machine, after all). But there are many errors like this one, and others mention even System assemblies, such as System.Net.Http.

```
Another error I get is the following: error CS0006: Metadata file 
'..\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.dll' could not be found 
[C:\a\1\s\MyProject.Application\MyProject.Application.csproj]
```

I never made a reference to any CodeAnalysis assembly so I'm not sure why they're being invoked.

Anyhow, I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors. I made sure the assemblies are not checked in, so as to force a restore of assemblies, to no avail. I can't understand why it does compile in my machine but in the CI Build it does not, other than a problem with the hosting environment that performs the build, or a problem with the template I'm using for the build.

To test the latter, I created a new CI Build, this time using Visual Studio template. The build still fails, but all the warning messages and the missing reference errors I got previously are gone, yet I still get the code analysis errors, plus a new one:

```
[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\
Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): Error : Assets file 
'C:\a\1\s\MyProject\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a 
NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

Which seems strange, given that the CI Build template performs a NuGet package restore, which was marked as successfull.

Another test I did, was to remove the ASP.NET Core project from my solution and tried the build, and voilà, it worked. So the problem seems not to be the class libraries nor the console application, but rather the ASP.NET Core application itself.

So, my question is, what am I missing? Am I missing a configuration step?

Comment: You can also try to use these task to build your asp.net core project https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core#add-the-tasks

Comment: Thank you @Marina-MSFT but alas, it still fails. The second task described in the article, Build: Visual Studio Build, still fails with the same errors I had with VS Build:

    2017-04-27T20:24:58.8707453Z   CSC : error CS0006: 
    Metadata file  '..\packages\
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.1.1.0\analyzers
    \dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.dll' could not be found 
    [C:\a\1\s\MyProject.Application\MyProject.Application.csproj]

Comment: could you upload somewhere the entire build log? you should check whether the restored packages are the ones you expects first of all. Also,you should check whether checking out the entire git repository on your own machine (in a new dir) and compiling it works too. The facts it works just on one single directory on your machine means little.

Comment: Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive? If you can reproduce this issue with new projects, you can share the sample projects on the OneDrive too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't trust the ASPNET core template in TFS just yet. It has lingering and hidden issues. It hasn't worked for me much.

Personally, I add a couple of `command line` steps in the build pipeline and do manual `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` in appropriate order before doing the actual sol build.

Comment: Ok, I could try it. Do you use any specific parameters to both restore and build? Thanks!